# question about dns

Tags: domain-name-system, bind

how to add multiple domainnames in named.conf file for both forward and reverse lookup zones

Comment: As a general rule RTFM answers are unwelcome here but I'm afraid it's the only one of any value in this case. If you aren't going to bother to read even the most basic documentation please move away from that machine and let someone else do it. There are more than enough screwed up DNS servers in the world already.

Answer (score 1):

If this is a serious question, you do it like so

For reverse zones (note the backwards IP address in "0.168.192.in-addr.arpa") :

```
zone "0.168.192.in-addr.arpa" {
    type master;
    file "db.192.168.0.0";
};
```

For "normal" zones:

```
zone "domain.com" {
        type master;
        file "db.domain.com";
        allow-transfer {
                trusted;
        };
};
```